# Trouble with updating array elements in a for-loop

Tags: python, numpy

I want to redefine array elements in my function `roll`

```
roll_current = 0

def roll(t):
    global roll_current

    # Generate array of the same numbers
    roll_current_ =  np.full((len(t)), roll_current)

    delta_roll_ = 0.1 - np.exp(-t)
    diff_ = roll_current_ - delta_roll_     

    # Update roll_current_ array
    for i, x in enumerate(roll_current_):
        if diff_[i]>0:
            roll_current_[i] = x - abs(diff_[i]) # x is equal to roll_current_[i] 
        elif diff_[i]<0:
            roll_current_[i] = x + abs(diff_[i]) 

    # Save value for the last time step
    roll_current = roll_current_[-1] # Scalar

    return roll_current_
```

But if I use `-=` or `+=`assignment or the code above then `roll_current_` array doesn't change and the following lines

```
t = np.linspace(0,4,10)
roll(t)
```

give `array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in your code:

The `fill` method fills an array with the value of `roll_current` which is an integer. Thus the array will also be of type `int`. Then in the `for`-loop all the values you are trying to set are between -1 and 1 and are therefor rounded to zero.
To solve the problem, change this line

```
roll_current_ =  np.full((len(t)), roll_current)
```

to this

```
roll_current_ =  np.full((len(t)), roll_current, dtype = np.float)
```

Alternatively you could just initialize `roll_current` like this:

```
roll_current = 0.
```

Comment: Thanks it saved me) But what do you mean when say "Alternatively you could just initialize `roll_current` like this" ? Because it seems I use exactly this type of initialization

Comment: Do you mean `roll_current_ = 0`?

Comment: The difference is the point behind the zero. When you write `roll_current = 0` python will use the type `int`, when you write `roll_current = 0.` or `roll_current = 0.0` it will be a `float` and since `roll_current_ ` is initialized with the value of `roll_current` it will also be an array of floats

Comment: Got it. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If you do a print of `roll_current_ =  np.full((len(t)), roll_current)`
output:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

probably you doesnt want this.

Please dont use globals if you can avoid it, why not `def roll(t, roll_current)`?

At for loop dont update the same array you are iterating, instead build another array appending the new items.

Comment: Thanks, problem had the different nature as @markuscosinus mentioned